# Swift 3 can't figure out my http put does not work

Tags: xcode, http, swift3, request, http-put

I am trying to send a put request to my server however the response I get is wierd.

If I add this to postman:

```
{
            "firstName": req.body.firstName,
            "lastName": req.body.lastName,
            "email": req.body.email,
            "role": req.body.role,
            "birthday": new Date(req.body.birthday),
            "sex": req.body.sex,
            "password": pw
}
```

I get a 200 from my server. However in my Swift application I get a 500.

My Put method looks like this:

```
func putUser(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String, emailCurrent: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, emailNew: String,
                 role: Int, sex: String, password: String){

        print("vi kører putUser med denne accessToken \(accessToken) og refreshToken \(refreshToken)")

        let urlPath = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/users/user/\(emailCurrent)"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
        request.addValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "accessToken")
        request.addValue(refreshToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "refreshToken")
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"



        let postString = "firstName=\(firstName)&lastName=\(lastName)&email=\(emailNew)&role=\(role)&birthday=2010-09-08&sex=\(sex)&password=\(password)"



     //   let strinng = "firstName=\(firstName)&lastName=\(lastName)&email\(emailNew)&role=\(role)&birthday=2010-09-08&sex=\(sex)&password=\(password)"

        print()
        print()

        print("Here is postString from putUser: \(postString)")

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)



        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Task completed \(data) and response is xxxx")

//            print all info as a string. ---
                        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")



        })
        task.resume()

    }
```

The response data I get is as follows:

```
Here is postString from putUser:
firstName=abcd&lastName=bb&email=abc@gmail.com&role=1&birthday=2010-09-08&sex=female&password=123
Task completed Optional(169 bytes) and response is xxxx
responseString = <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>Unexpected token f</h1><h2></h2><pre></pre></body></html>
```

I have a feeling it is because of my postString, however I cannot see the difference between the httpBody in my postman, and the one above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to do something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762597/post-request-in-objective-c-with-lyft-api-access-token#comment70716705_41762597 Because you are formatting your parameters as a GET, while in POSTMAN, it's like JSON.

Comment: @Larme this worked! I just had to add request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") and then your suggestion worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you formatted your `HTTPBody` is wrong.
You need to create a `(NS)Dictionary`.
Then, you can use `(NS)JSONSerialization` in order to transform that `(NS)Dictionary` into JSON as `(NS)Data`.
You can check the format by calling `(NS)String(data:encoding:)` on it.

Also, you may need to tell the server that you are giving JSON, by adding to the header "Content-Type":"application/json".
We also often add the length: "Content-Length":"lengthOfTheParametersData".

In Objective-C (I don't use Swift), but it should be easily translated:

//PUT parameters

```
NSDictionary *putParams = @{@"firstName":@"abcd",
                            @"lastName":@"bb",
                            @"email":@"abc@gmail.com",
                            @"role":@"1",
                            @"birthday":@"2010-09-08",
                            @"sex":@"female",
                            @"password":@"123"};
NSData *putData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:putParams options:0 error:nil];
[request setHTTPBody:putData];
```

//Header:

```
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [putData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

on my request. After that I could write my request like so:

```
let urlPath = "http://keebintest-pagh.rhcloud.com/login"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"



        let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
            "email": email,
            "password": password,


            ]
```